# "cut and paste" the last k elements of std::vector efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stdvector

Is it possible in C++11 "cut and paste" the last k elements of an std::vector A to a new std:::vector B in constant time?

One way would be to use `B.insert(A.end() - k, A.end())` and then use erase on A but these are both O(k) time operations.

Mau

Comment: No it's not possible in constant time.

Comment: it is possible in `log(n)` time if you are using BST instead of array for storing elements

Comment: It is possible in O(1) time if we use arrays instead of vectors, given that the source array does not grow after slicing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, vectors own their memory.

This operation is known as splice.  `forward_list` is ridiculously slow otherwise, but it does have an O(1) splice.

Typically, the process of deciding which elements to move is already O(n), so having the splice itself take O(n) time is not a problem.  The other operations being faster on vector more than make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in general, since (at least in the C++03 version -- there it's 23.2.4/1) the C++ standard guarantees that the memory used by a `vector<T>` is a single contiguous block.  Thus the only way to "transfer" more than a fixed number of elements in O(1) time would be if the receiving vector were empty, and you had somehow arranged to have it's allocated block of memory begin at the right place *inside* the first vector -- in which case the "transfer" could be argued to have taken no time at all.  (Deliberately overlapping objects in this way is almost certain to constitute Undefined Behaviour in theory -- and in practice, it's also very fragile, since any operation that invalidates iterators to a `vector<T>` can also reallocate memory, thus breaking things.)

If you're prepared to sacrifice a whole bunch of portability, I've heard it's possible to play OS-level (or hardware-level) tricks with virtual memory mapping to achieve tricks like no-overhead ring buffers.  Maybe these tricks could also be applied here -- but bear in mind that the assumption that the mapping of virtual to physical memory within a single process is one-to-one is very deeply ingrained, so you could be in for some surprises.